# How does the anti isomer below have a plane of symmetry? The R group and the H end up in opposite sides if you divide in half

Tags: symmetry

If we add substituents R to this structure, we can have two diastereoisomers with the two R groups on the same side (syn) of the flat ring or on opposite (anti) sides. Although the plane of the paper is no longer a plane of symmetry, neither isomer is chiral as the other plane bisects the substituents and is still a plane of symmetry.

How does the anti-diastereoisomer have a plane of symmetry?
[image: diamide]

Comment: The plane of symmetry *contains* both R's and both H's, so they don't move when reflected.

Comment: Exactly like it is drawn in the picture...

Answer (score 2):

The two $\ce{CHR}$ groups at opposite corners of the ring are co-planar, and both isomers are symmetric about this plane.

Yes, seeing a molecule in three dimensions when you have a paper drawing is difficult. In my day at school the recommendation was to use a kit to build a molecular model, which you could rotate to get different views. Today we can use computer images.

Comment: So, what is wrong this time? (Other than getting burned by Autocorrect, which forced an early-morning edit?)

Answer (score 2):

Both molecules have a plane of symmetry. The $\ce{R}$ groups lie on the plane of symmetry. Try visualizing it this way:

[image: anti and syn isomers showing plane of symmetry and achirality]

Unless the $\ce{R}$ groups are chiral, both the molecules can exist in an achiral conformation.

Also, likely, the ring is not planer because $\pu{120 ^\circ}$ is not the natural angle for the $\ce{N}$ atoms in (somewhat) $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridization.

Comment: Amide nitrogens are very much planar.

Comment: @orthocresol 'very much' being the keywords, the six-membered ring is strained in the planer configuration. Based on geometrical optimization, non-planarity adds stability.